# What is Format Painter shortcut in Excel 2011 for Mac?

Tags: ms-office, shortcut

I've been looking on the Internet for the shortcut to the Format Painter tool. No luck so far, it seems there's no shortcut for this tool. Maybe someone here knows better.

[image: Format Painter Icon]

Comment: The words to describe the icon you selected is the format painter shortcut in excel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This article here gave a detail guide on how to solve this quickly.

http://thelostgeeks.blogspot.com/2012/10/keyboard-shortcut-to-copypaste.html

Answer (score 9):

There is (now) a predefined shortcut for this

- To copy the format: <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- To paste the copied format: <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

There is no official keyboard shortcut for that. But you can customize a shortcut. Here's how:
http://thelostgeeks.blogspot.com/2012/10/keyboard-shortcut-to-copypaste.html

> Go to Tools-> Customize Keyboard. Select  "Edit" from categories. On
>   the right hand side select "Formatting". Go to "Press new shortcut
>   key" and type in a new shortcut. I used Command + Shift + v. And ,
>   click on "Add" . Close the window. All set. Now i can just use the
>   normal copy ( Command + c)  the cells from which i want to copy the
>   formatting. Then go the cell where i want to paste the format and hit
>   the keyboard shortcut (Command + Shift + v). BAM ! the format is
>   copied.

Answer (score -1):

Within Microsoft Office, one can use:

- Cmd + Opt + c to copy format
- Cmd + Opt + v to paste format